# About modifying the parameter of a functor

Tags: c++, templates, stl, functor

I have the following comparator for string objects

```
struct Comparator{

  int x;

  bool operator() (string a, string b) {

    int i = 1;

    if(a < b) {
      i = -1;
    } 

    i*= x;

    if(i==-1) {
      return true;
    } 

    return false;

  }

};
```

As you can see, it has a parameter x. when it is = 1 the comparison of strings is normal and when it is =-1 the comparison is inverted.

When using it in a method like `sort` for `vector` elements I can give the object instance of this comparator with the right `x`, but when I want to give this comparator to a template class like `set`, I need to give a class and not an object instance. So the only solution I see is to make `x` static. Is there a better solution?

Here is the example of a main where I would like to use this comparator:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

  vector<string> vec;

  vec.push_back("c");
  vec.push_back("a");
  vec.push_back("b");

  Comparator comp;

  comp.x = 1; // for normal comparison
  comp.x = -1; // for inverse comparison

  sort(vec.begin(),vec.end(), comp); // here I can give the functor instance

  for(vector<string>::iterator it = vec.begin() ; it != vec.end(); it++)
  {
    cout << *it << endl;
  }

  set<string, Comparator> ss; // but here I must give the name of the functor class

  ss.insert("c");
  ss.insert("a");
  ss.insert("b");

  for(set<string>::iterator it = ss.begin() ; it != ss.end(); it++)
  {
    cout << *it << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the relevant constructors of `set` also take an instance of `Comp` class.

```
 set<string, Comparator> ss(Comparator(-1));
```

Now you only need a constructor for `Comparator` that initializes its member `x` with an appropriate value.

That said, the standard library already comes with a comparator class for this purpose:

```
set<string, std::greater<std::string> > ss;
```

Comment: Thanks. This is the clean way I was looking for. 

About your second remark, my functor is a bit more complicated but I just simplified it to the binary case for the question. However I didnt know about std::greater though :) so thanks again

Comment: I just noticed that this creates a new object every time i need to declare a set. And I want to use only one object for all my sets that uses the same instance of Comparator. Is there a better way then?

Comment: Set container holds a copy of the comparator, so not really. What's the problem with that, anyway? A struct containing a single `int` is cheap to copy, just as a function pointer would be (if you chose to switch to that).

Comment: The problem is that it s not just an int and not even a single parameter. and our application is performance-critical. Why does the container set need to make a copy? It would be nice if the set<string, Comparator> ss(comp) will only hold a reference to comp

Comment: I need to go read about that "function pointer" that you mentioned and see how to apply it to this. It might be the solution I need...

Comment: Nope, the function pointer doesn t work as the number of values that x can take is infinite. I guess I simplified the example way too much. I accept your answer and I will ask a new question that reflects better what i want. thanks anyway

Comment: You can make `Comparator` internaly hold a pointer to shared instance of a class that holds the data. That'll make the comparator cheaper to copy but it'll introduce another level of indirection, which might turn out to be worse for performance. OTOH, a omparator is only copied once when the set is constructed, but called many times.

Comment: Thanks man. I really appreciate your help. I guess those are pretty much all the possible solutions and i just need to decide.

Answer (score 0):

That will not work: a < b does not(!) mean b < a.

You might utilize std::string::compare:

```
bool operator() (const std::string& a, const std::string& b) {
    int result = a.compare(b) * x;
    return result < 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes I agree but i just made a fast example to explain my issue.